# Changing static URL regarding the environment

Tags: url, static, playframework-2.0

Using Play Framework 2.0.4, I'd like to define my static content URLS differently regarding the environment.

In DEV mode, it would be /public/{here}, so using the default configuration of

```
GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

is good, but in PROD, I want to use the http://static.mydomain.com/ base URL.

At first, I thought about changing the Assets like this :

```
 GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="http://static.mydomain.com/", file)
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

So I was thinking about using a static method that would look in the `application.conf` file for a `application.staticBaseUrl` parameter, and return either `/public/{here}` or `http://static.mydomain.com/{here}`, or anything defined in the application.conf param.

But I'm not sure if it's the best way, neither if there isn't already a better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add static wrapper ie in you `Application` controller:

```java
public static String wrapLink(play.mvc.Call uri) {
    return wrapLink(uri.toString());
}

public static String wrapLink(String uri) {
    return (Play.application().isDev()) ? "/public" + uri : "http://domain.tld" + uri;
}
```

so you can use it in your views with:

```scala
link from String:
    @Application.wrapLink("/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")

or from Call
    @Application.wrapLink(routes.Application.index)
```

#### Expanded version

I'm using also expanded version of this when working with several CDN's ie (or using dummy subdomain-CDNs for faster resource downloading):

`Application.conf`

```
cdn.cdn1="http://cdn1.domain.tld"
cdn.cdn2="http://cdn2.domain.tld"
```

controller:

```java
public static String wrapLink(String cdnId, String uri) {
    return (Play.application().isDev()) 
        ? "/public" + uri 
        : Play.application().configuration().getString("cdn."+cdnId)+ uri;
}
```

view:

```scala
@Application.wrapLink("cdn1", "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")
@Application.wrapLink("cdn2", "/images/abc.jpg")
```

Comment: Does using `Play.application().configuration()` hit the config file every time or Play loads the configuration file in memory ?

Comment: Don't know, anyway reading it every time would be bad concept so I assume that's stored in the memory.